# I don't even know how to get access permission of nested interface in Eclipse. [Scope issue]

Tags: java, eclipse, nested, directory

Here I have a hierarchical view set up of folders in Eclipse. 
I have a model package/source folder. Inside is a nested package/source folder of which will contain several interface classes.

On the outer level of this, in the model folder, I have a class 'WrigleyHostel'. This implements the interface.

The problem here is IFacility/the interface is not in scope of it. Pls help.

Error: IFacility cannot be resolved to a type
[image]

Comment: Let's use eclipse: press `<ctrl>-o`

Comment: Sorry, but I definitely can't reproduce it. If it's still a problem, please give more context.

Comment: I have folder src >> model > WrigleyHostel
package src >> model >> interface > interface 1, interface 2 interface 3
how to get WrigleyHostel implement methods in interface1,2,3

Comment: In which way is this related to the original problem?

Comment: @blafasel I suppose we could say this is secondary of the solution..., still squiggly red lines do not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `import model.interfaces.IFacility` underneath the package declaration. You only have visibility to classes in the *same* package.

There's no such thing as a "subpackage" or "nested package" in Java - packages `com.foo` and `com.foo.bar` may look related because they share folder structure, but to Java, they're different packages.

A "nested interface" is something different entirely - an example would be if you defined `IFacility` interface inside the `WrigleyHostel` class file.

Comment: When you say Put import model.interfaces.IFacility, do you mean that after this I should be able to add the unimplemented methods into the class that implements IFacility? No long red tilda appears under the WrigleyHostel class after the interfaces have their importation. 
I've looked a round. Sources say to go to build path >> use as resource in the interface source folder. Don't think it works

Comment: You don't need to futz with build paths to use interfaces in the same project. Think of how you would write this if you were using notepad. Just import the interface and implement it.